# Swift cambiar color de activacion al hacer foco en textield

Tags: swift, xcode

Tengo el siguiente textfield

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo cambiar el color azul para que no aparesca como cuando no le doy foco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El textfield es personalizado los bordes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar un UITapGestureRecognizer para cuando se toca la pantalla para quitar el teclado

Algo asi:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handler))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
@objc func handler() {
    self.view.endEditing = true
    //Aqui va el codigo para quitar el color de la linea
}
```